# Meteor: adding a class to a table element on a click event

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've got a table with a few table rows and so I've created a click event which updates `myCollection` when particular `td` elements are clicked, this works fine.  What I want to do is display a bootstrap "tick" to show that this element is "active" when clicked.

If I run `$('.activate').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok');` on the console it adds the classes to all elements with the `.activate` class and not the one that triggered the event.  I can also run this line from within the function below with the same result.

I can't seem to get this working at all with the following code:

```
'click .activate': function (event, template) {

     var id=event.target.getAttribute("data-id");

      myCollection.update({_id: id}, {$set: {status: "active"}});

      // I've tried variations of the line below with no success
      $(this).closest("td").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok");

 }
```

Also when the page reloads I'll want to display the "tick" in the correct place.  I'm not sure how best to do that.  I can't do this for example:

```
{{#each myCollection}}
  {{#if status=="active"}}
     <p>display stuff</p>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Any ideas how I can get this working?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside of the event handler, `this` is the context of the element that was clicked, not the element itself. The more 'meteoric' way is to use reactivity, rather than jQuery, to update the DOM.

```
<template name="table">
  {{#each myCollection}}
    {{> tr}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="tr">
  <td class="activate">Activate</td>
  <td>
    {{#if active}}
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    {{/if}}
  </td>
</template>
```

```js
Template.table.myCollection = function () {
  return myCollection.find();
};

Template.tr.active = function () {
  return this.status === "active";
};

Template.tr.events({
  'click .activate': function (event, template) {
    myCollection.update(this._id, {$set: {status: "active"}});
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice one Neil, that makes perfect sense!  I'll give it go :)  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on a persistent status (which seems to be the case here), Neil's answer is the way to go.

If you just need some temporary UI effect, you can use the following jQuery:

```
$(event.target).addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok");
```

(nearly same code you did try, but with `$(event.target)` instead of `$(this)`)